# Jquery Datatable drag and drop a row from one table to another

Tags: jquery, json, datatables

I am using jquery.dataTables.js and I'm trying to drag and drop rows from one table to another and vice-versa from table 2 to table1 like this sample: http://jsfiddle.net/yf47u/

Above sample was with json so I would like to make the same work with my json sample.

this is my jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/f7debwj2/12/

html:

```
<br>
<br>
<h1>
 table1
</h1><br>
<br>
<table id="example" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First name</th>
      <th>Place</th>
      <th>Order</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>

<br>
<br>
<h1>
 table 2
</h1><br>
<br>
<table id="example2" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First name</th>
      <th>Place</th>
      <th>checkbox</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dt = $('#example').dataTable();
  dt.fnDestroy();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  var url = 'http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/clmDuyndua?indent=2';
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    ajax: url,
    createdRow: function(row, data, dataIndex) {
      $(row).attr('id', 'row-' + dataIndex);
    },
    rowReorder: {
      dataSrc: 'order',
    },
    columns: [{
      data: 'order'
    }, {
      data: 'name'
    }, {
      data: 'place'
    }]
  });
  table.rowReordering();

});


$(document).ready(function() {
  var dt = $('#example2').dataTable();
  dt.fnDestroy();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  var url = 'http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cnmZgfsBKa?indent=2';
  var table = $('#example2').DataTable({
    ajax: url,
    createdRow: function(row, data, dataIndex) {
      $(row).attr('id', 'row-' + dataIndex);
    },
    rowReorder: {
      dataSrc: 'order',
    },
    columns: [{
      data: 'order'
    }, {
      data: 'name'
    }, {
      data: 'checkbox'
    }]
  });
  table.rowReordering();

});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').on('mouseenter', 'input', function() {
    $('.btn').prop('disabled', true);
  });
  $('body').on('mouseout', 'input', function() {
    $('.btn').prop('disabled', false);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is my solution to this problem based on your code. It's possible to drag and drop rows from one table to the other one, but I was compelled to change values of the FirstName column dynamically, because otherwise a table would consider two rows with an identical FirstName equal, which would be a problem when removing one of those identical rows. Generally, tables should have a unique key in such cases.

JavaScript:

```
    var rowCache;

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var dt = $('#example').dataTable();
        dt.fnDestroy();
    });     

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var dt = $('#example2').dataTable();
        dt.fnDestroy();
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
        rowCache = [];

        var url = 'http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/clmDuyndua?indent=2';
        var table = $('#example').DataTable({
            ajax: url,
            createdRow: function(row, data, dataIndex) {
              $(row).attr('id', 'row-' + dataIndex);
            },
            rowReorder: {
              dataSrc: 'order',
            },
            columns: [{
              data: 'order'
            }, {
              data: 'name'
            }, {
              data: 'place'
            }]
        });

        table.rowReordering();

        table.on('mousedown', 'tbody tr', function () {
            var $row = $(this);
            var r = table.rows(function (i, data) {
                return data.order == $row.children().first().text();
            });

            if (r[0].length > 1)
                r = r.rows(r[0][0]);    

            rowCache.push({ selector: 'example', row: r });
        });

        table.on('mouseup', mouseUp);
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
      var url = 'http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cnmZgfsBKa?indent=2';
      var table = $('#example2').DataTable({
        ajax: url,
        createdRow: function(row, data, dataIndex) {
          $(row).attr('id', 'row-' + dataIndex);
        },
        rowReorder: {
          dataSrc: 'order',
        },
        columns: [{
          data: 'order'
        }, {
          data: 'name'
        }, {
          data: 'checkbox'
        }]
      });
      table.rowReordering();

        table.on('mousedown', 'tbody tr', function () {
            var $row = $(this);
            var r = table.rows(function (i, data) {
                return data.order == $row.children().first().text();
            });

            if (r[0].length > 1)
                r = r.rows(r[0][0]);    

            rowCache.push({ selector: 'example2', row: r });
        });

        table.on('mouseup', mouseUp);
    });

    function mouseUp(event)
    {
        var id = $(document.elementsFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY))
            .filter('table')
            .attr('id');

        if (id && event.currentTarget.id != id)
        {
            rowCache.every(function (el, i) {
                if (el.selector != id)
                {                   
                    var data = el.row.data();

                    if (data.length > 0) {

                        if (!data[0].checkbox)
                            data[0].checkbox = "<input type='checkbox' />"

                        el.row.remove().draw();
                        var $target = $("#" + id).DataTable();

                        if ($target.rows()[0].length > 0)
                        {
                            var rowsArray = $target.rows().data().toArray();
                            data[0].order = rowsArray[rowsArray.length - 1].order + 1;
                        }
                        else
                            data[0].order = 1;

                        $target.rows.add(data.toArray()).draw();
                    }
                }}
            );
        }   

        rowCache = [];
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('body').on('mouseenter', 'input', function() {
            $('.btn').prop('disabled', true);
        });
        $('body').on('mouseout', 'input', function() {
            $('.btn').prop('disabled', false);
        });
    });
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jahn08/f7debwj2/34/

Comment: thank you so much man for this help, just 2 more questions can i block the drag drop from table 1 to table 2? also instead of move the whole row could I just move a column? and replace? sample: drag drop the column place from table 2 to into place from table 1? and update that field with new data?   instead of move the whole row?, thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. The second question is more elaborate and requires some time to change the example. Given your goal, there is a necessity to apply almost the same logic, but to the cells property instead of the rows one. As for blocking, sure, it's possible to block that kind of drag and drop, you'll only have to remove the mouse events from the first table. Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/jahn08/f7debwj2/35/

Comment: ok np thank you, I changed the plugin and i am using the official one from datatables, so it is possible to make your code works in that jsfiddle? : http://jsfiddle.net/f7debwj2/37/   thank you

Comment: Yeah, indeed, in this new version the MouseUp event stopped working as it expected, so I substituted the event with a global one. Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/jahn08/f7debwj2/41/